# How to create an executable bash script for these commands?

Tags: shell, shell-script, sudo, su

I wish to create an executable bash script that will run the following commands as root, that is, using sudo su

```
iptables-save | awk '/^[*]/ { print $1 } 
                     /^:[A-Z]+ [^-]/ { print $1 " ACCEPT" ; }
                     /COMMIT/ { print $0; }' | iptables-restore
```

My first attempt at bash scripting is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
iptables-save | awk '/^[*]/ { print $1 } 
                     /^:[A-Z]+ [^-]/ { print $1 " ACCEPT" ; }
                     /COMMIT/ { print $0; }' | iptables-restore
sleep 3;
exit 0
```

Could someone correct the above and make it workable?

Comment: First of all, don't use `sudo` to run `su`! You can use `sudo -i` for `sudo su -` or `sudo -s` for `sudo su`

Comment: @Artur Szymczak What is the difference between `sudo -i` and `sudo -s` in plain English? I have read the man pages and am still clueless. (I do not have a technical or IT background.) The man pages do not provide examples of instances where one might use `sudo -i` over `sudo -s`

Comment: `sudo -i` gives you login shell. It means, that shell configuration files, like `/etc/profile` are applied - you get shell, similar to the one, when you directly login on given user. `sudo -s` don't do this, giving you non-login shell - like `su` - just switch user.

Comment: @Artur Szymczak Thanks for the explanation. Just to make sure I understand it, when I wish to edit or make changes to files in, for example, `/etc/default/grub` or `/dev/snd`, I must use `sudo -i`. Can you provide an example in which I have to use `sudo -s`?

Comment: You could edit any files using `sudo -s` and `sudo -i`. The problem is related to environment variables, like PATH. In some distributions, you couldn't see some commands, because they are in `/sbin` dir, and PATH for normal user, doesn't include it. THe same problem is with DISPLAY, when you would like to run GUI command.

Comment: @ArturSzymczak Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell scripts aren't quite the same as typing at a terminal.
What's going to happen here is that `iptables-save` is going to wait for `sudo su` to complete, and then run.  What you want is to run `iptables-save` inside the `sudo`.

Secondly, `sudo su` is among the ranks of 'useless use of' examples. The proper equivalent is
`sudo -i`.

There are 2 approaches you can take to solving this.

#### Method 1

```
sudo -i <<'EOF'
iptables-save | awk '/^[*]/ { print $1 } 
                 /^:[A-Z]+ [^-]/ { print $1 " ACCEPT" ; }
                 /COMMIT/ { print $0; }' | iptables-restore
EOF
```

This basically launches a root shell and sends that command through the shell.
The reason we don't don't just add a `sudo` in front of both the `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` commands is that it will launch 2 `sudo`s at the same time. This does not work well if they both end up trying to prompt for the password.
So this solution works around the issue by only launching a single `sudo`.

**One line**
As requested in your comment, you can do this in a single line, but it becomes much harder to read.

```
sudo -i sh -c 'iptables-save | awk '\''/^[*]/ { print $1 }; /^:[A-Z]+ [^-]/ { print $1 " ACCEPT" ; }; /COMMIT/ { print $0; }'\'' | iptables-restore'
```

#### Method 2

```
sudo -v
sudo -n iptables-save | awk '/^[*]/ { print $1 } 
             /^:[A-Z]+ [^-]/ { print $1 " ACCEPT" ; }
             /COMMIT/ { print $0; }' | sudo -n iptables-restore
```

This solution runs `sudo` the first time, without any command, simply a `-v`. This causes `sudo` to prompt for your password if your session is expired. Then any commands run within that session expiration window won't require a password. So launching 2 `sudo`s at the same time is no longer an issue as neither of them will prompt (we add `-n` to make absolutely sure of this. It'll throw an error if it tries).

Comment: The first example is definitely best - the second only works if `sudo` is configured to store credentials for a length of time - which is, admittedly, extremely likely.

Comment: @Patrick: Thanks for the detailed explanation, even though I only understood about 50% of what you wrote. I have a question: Could you transform the 3 lines of the code into a single line? (The code that starts with `iptables-save | awk '/^[*]/ { print $1 }`)

Comment: @Patrick: Could you also answer Question 2 please? I have edited my original post to include Question 2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user66229 You should ask that as another question. It's entirely unrelated to the original.

Comment: @Patrick As advised, I have created a new question referenced by the following link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131937/will-i-be-prompted-for-the-sudo-password-a-second-time. But would it be possible for you to answer my question regarding how to combine the 3 lines of code into a single one? Or is that a totally new question?

Comment: @user66229 done. answer is updated