# Will I be prompted for the sudo password a second time?

Tags: sudo, password, time

This is what I plan to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -i <<'EOF'
iptables-save | awk '/^[*]/ { print $1 } 
                 /^:[A-Z]+ [^-]/ { print $1 " ACCEPT" ; }
                 /COMMIT/ { print $0; }' | iptables-restore
EOF
```

I will save the above and call it cleariptables.sh. I will set it as executable.

It will be placed in a folder called bin in the following path: /home/cymbal/bin/

(where cymbal is the username)

I will create a shortcut to cleariptables.sh on the desktop. The contents of the shortcut will be:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon[en_US]=nm-device-wired
Name[en_US]=ClearIPtables
Exec=gksudo /home/cymbal/bin/cleariptables.sh
Comment[en_US]=Flush iptables filters
Name=ClearIPtables
Comment=Flush iptables script
Icon=nm-device-wired
```

Whenever I click on the desktop shortcut, I will be prompted to enter the password and the script will run.

Question: Clicking on the desktop shortcut prompts me for the password. As there is a *sudo -i* in the script, will I be prompted again for the password?

Comment: If you're interested in viewing the output or any errors in the script, this question might be helpful too:
[How can I make a script that opens terminal windows and executes commands in them?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **NOPASSWD** directive in your `sudoers` file.

Add this line to your `/etc/sudoers` file

```
your_login ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script
```

When editing this file, you should use the `visudo` command instead of a regular text editor. This will check for syntax errors before saving your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What does `your_login` represent? Is it my username?

Comment: Yes it is **cymbal**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now, if I add your recommended line to my `/etc/sudoers` file, will my username become `root` from that point onwards? I do not want that to happen. During Debian installation, I expressly chose not to allow log in as root.

Comment: No ! Only the given command is run as root. It's not a `root` login !

Comment: But any files by your script, will have the `root` as owner :-)

Comment: I have learned something new, thanks to you.

Answer (score 6):

No, you should not be prompted for a password again. The script will be running as root due to the `gksudo`. In my experience, `sudo` never asks for password if you are already root (although I couldn't find this explicitly documented).

Comment: You are right. I was not prompted for a password again.